# Error: Limit controls must follow a math operator

Tags: equations

I need to create the following expression in **Latex**:

[image]

I am trying to do it using the following equation command:

```
\begin{equation}
    I_\sum (x)
\end{equation}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Limit controls must follow a math operator. I_\sum
```

The 'weird' thing is that the expression `I_\sum (x)` seems to be correct when I insert it in the [codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) website.

How can I create that expression?

**Note**: I'm using TexStudio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The correct expression is *always* `<letter>_{<subscript>}`. In *some* cases the braces can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @egreg, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a standard LaTeX class (`article`, ...) and without math packages, the code snippet runs without problems. Package `amsmath` redefines the symbol for additional features that does not work smoothly as naked subscript. This is fixed by putting the symbol in curly braces, a math subformula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    I_{\sum} (x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\sum` is intended as big operator for summation. The symbol is also quite large as subscript. A smaller sigma is available as `\Sigma`, which also works without braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    I_\Sigma (x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \Sigma]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `I_\Sigma (x)` expression worked like a charm.